# Why are these two double integrals different ? A question on Dirac delta distribution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-measure, dirac-delta

Consider the following two integrals:

\begin{align}
I_1&:=\iint_{0\leq x,\, y\leq 1,\,x=y}\,dx\, dy,\\
I_2&:=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \delta(x-y)\,dx \,dy.
\end{align}

I believe $I_1=0$ because it is the measure "surface area" of the line segment $y=x$ inside a two dimensional rectangle.

From the properties of the delta function, we have

$$I_2=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \delta(x-y)\, dx\, dy=\int_0^1 1 \,dy=1$$

as
$$\int_0^1 \delta(x-y)\, dx =1$$ for any $y\in ]0,1[.$

**Question**: I understand very well that the integrands are different in $I_1$ and $I_2$. In $I_1$, the integrand is
the characteristic function
$\chi_{0\leq x,y\leq 1,x=y}(x,y)$. But these integrands are different on a negligible set... I am confused!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to make this about double integrals.  Your question would apply just as well to the two integrals  $$\int_{[0,1]}\chi_{\{0\}}(x)\,dx=0$$ and $$\int_{[0,1]}\delta(x)\,dx=1,$$ which are different even though $\delta$ and $\chi_{\{0\}}$ are the same everywhere except at $0$.  The explanation for this is simply that $\delta$ is not actually a function and its "integral" is not actually an integral in the usual sense.  It's a theorem that if two integrable functions agree except on a set of measure zero, then their integrals are the same.  But $\delta$ is not a function at all, so that theorem doesn't apply.  Instead, $\int_{[0,1]}\delta(x)\,dx$, though written as an "integral", is actually simply defined as the evaluation of the distribution $\delta$ on the constant function $1$.  Since $\delta$ is by definition the distribution that takes a function and outputs that function evaluated at $0$, this gives the answer of $1$.

Intuitively, $\delta$ is a "function" that gets infinitely large at the point $0$, such that even though it's just one single point, the "area" under it somehow manages to be positive.  But it's not actually literally the function $\mathbb{R}\to[-\infty,\infty]$ that is $\infty$ at $0$ and $0$ elsewhere; that is an actual genuine integrable function whose integral is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

What happens is that the delta "function" is not a function. Integration against $\delta\, dx$ simply means integration against the delta measure $$\delta(E)=\begin{cases}1,&\ 0\in E\\ 0,&\ 0\not\in E\end{cases} $$